# Posterior Probability Density for a set of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

I've been reading Watanabe's [book](https://www.routledge.com/Mathematical-Theory-of-Bayesian-Statistics/Watanabe/p/book/9780367734817) on Bayesian Statistics, and had trouble with the posterior probability density formula for a set of random variable pairs.

For a set of random variables $X^n=(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ subject to $q(x_1)q(x_2)...q(x_n)$ i.e. independent random variables (each of which are $\Bbb R^N$), the posterior of the model parameter $w \in W \subseteq \Bbb R^d$ is a straightforward application of the Bayes rule (where the prior represents $\varphi(w)$):

$$
p\left(w \mid X^n\right)=\frac{1}{Z\left(X^n\right)} \varphi(w) \prod_{i=1}^n p\left(X_i \mid w\right)
$$

$$
Z\left(X^n\right)=\int \varphi(w) \prod_{i=1}^n p\left(X_i \mid w\right) d w
$$

However, Watanabe at (1.9) then claims, for $(X^n,Y^n) = ((X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2),...,(X_n,Y_n))$ subject to $q(x_1,y_1)q(x_2,y_2)...q(x_n,y_n)$ i.e. independent random variable pairs (each sample on $\Bbb R^m \times \Bbb R^n$), the following is true:

$$
p\left(w \mid X^n, Y^n\right)=\frac{1}{Z\left(X^n, Y^n\right)} \varphi(w) \prod_{i=1}^n p\left(Y_i \mid X_i, w\right)
$$

$$
Z\left(X^n, Y^n\right)=\int \varphi(w) \prod_{i=1}^n p\left(Y_i \mid X_i, w\right) d w
$$

But this doesn't make sense; it seems to ignores $P(X_i \mid w)$ for the factorization of $P(X_i, Y_i)$ within $\prod$, nor do they seem to cancel out (since one's within the integral at the denominator). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you are missing anything.
In fact, you are totally right in pointing this out!
There seem to be some assumptions hidden in the notation, in particular, in the formulation "for an arbitrary pair $(p(y|x,w),\varphi(w))$".
I suppose that it might be implied that $X^{n}$ and $w$ are independent (and also that $X_{i}$ and $Y_{i}$ are conditionally independent given $w$), but, in my humble opinion, it is a somewhat counterintuitive introduction to posterior distributions.

Comment: Thanks - and yes, the notations really are counterintuitive. Do you have a recommendation for a different material that cover similar materials as this book?

Comment: This question is not easy to answer. It really depends on your background (how strong is your mathematics/probability theory/statistics) and on what you want to do with it - learn the theoretical background or apply Bayesian statistics in practice (say, using R).
I think a good start would be  "Bayesian Data Analysis" by Gelman, et al., which is a great book and you can have a quick look at the free online pdf, whether it suits you or not: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/BDA3.pdf